# Toggle @import 'light' or @import 'dark' via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

My goal is to use a darkmode toggle in one of my projects. I also use the SASS (.scss) architecture rather than plain CSS due to the scale of the project.

I had the following in mind: throughout my .scss files I will use variables for the light color mode (e.g. $white and $black for bg and text-color respectively) and the dark color mode (e.g. $black and $white for bg and text-color respectively, so the reverse of aforementioned).

I want to achieve darkmode by selectively importing one or the other in my main.scss via @import.

In short, I would like to have a JS script which allows to toggle whether @import 'dark' or @import 'light' will be entered in my main.scss.

So: I press a button to switch to darkmode and then my main.scss will be altered so (e.g. in line 1) it will say "@import 'dark'" and when I press it again this very line will change to "@import 'light'".

Can somebody help me with this? I have been cracking my brain over it for days...

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know much about sass, but you can achieve the light and dark mode with just html, css and js.

```js
const inputEl = document.querySelector(".input");

const bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");

inputEl.checked = updateBody();

function updateBody() {
    if (inputEl.checked) {
        bodyEl.style.background = "black";
    } else {
        bodyEl.style.background = "white";
    }
}

inputEl.addEventListener("input", ()=>{
    updateBody();
    
});
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    align-items: center;
    transition: .4s;
}

.label {
    width: 80px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: lightgray;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.input {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* z-index: 1; */
}

.circle {
    width: 34px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 34px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    top: 3px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 3px;
    animation: toggleOff 0.4s linear forwards;
}

.input:checked + .label {
    background-color: white;
}

.input:checked + .label .circle {
    animation: toggleOn 0.4s linear forwards;
    background-color: black;
}

@keyframes toggleOn {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(40px);
    }
    
}

@keyframes toggleOff {
    0%{
        transform: translateX(40px);
    }
    100%{
        transform: translateX(0);
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Dark Mode Toggle</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="checkbox"  id="dark-mode" class="input">
    <label for="dark-mode" class="label">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </label>
   
</body>
</html>
```